# Why do I need a loopback adapter on the target hosts of a Virtual IP?

Tags: networking, loopback

I recently ran into a problem involving virtual IPs for the first time. The virtual IP targets two different (as far as I can tell, physical) hosts. The hosts are linux, but I don't know what software or environment the virual IP itself is using.

The problem: The requests that were sent to the 2nd host were all timing out (the 1st host was fine).

The solution: Start up a loopback adapter with the Virtual IP on the 2nd host (the first host already had this).

My question: Why is the loopback adapter nessecary?

My understanding of loopback is that requests are passed back up the network stack without being broadcast over a physical adapter. However, the physical hosts receive the requests from another place, so I do not understand why the loopback adapter was neccesary. The requests do not orgininate from the hosts themselves (or do they...) so I do not see what function the loopback adapter is performing.

Comment: Please [edit] and add details of the OS and method of creating the VIPs.

Comment: I added the info about the target hosts but I don't know about the VIP server itself.

Comment: So the request goes to VIP_IP, which then forwards to PHYS_IP1 or PHYS_IP2, but they won't respond unless they both have VIP_IP on a loopback adapter?

Comment: I am guessing the linux hosts are running some sort a routing/switching configuration? In which case the loopback interface will actually be visible to the rest of the network. It's also a very common solution on Cisco units to do it this way, to actually attach a loopback interface to the network, so the unit can be reached and managed.

Comment: @Paul That's right. For the avoidance of doubt, they don't *both* have to have to loopback adapter. PHYS_IP1 had it, so responded, PHYS_IP2 didn't have it, so didn't respond.

Comment: @Kris Interesting. I'd never heard of a loopback interface being attached to the network before.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Yeah it is quite interesting, I guess my Cisco education finally had some use! :P

Comment: @Adam Seems like the virtual server is not correctly rewriting the packets. Is there a way to find out what it is?